# Access collection field in Spring Repository with custom Query

Tags: java, spring-data, jpql

I'm trying to make a query to search all Posts from my application containing a keyword on the content or on the tags name but only those who are public. I'm trying to make the JPQL search but I don't know how to access the tags.name property.

Note: `Post` is an entity which has a List of `Tag` entity;

I have tried this but it's not working (as I expected):

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE (p.content LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(:keyword),'%' OR p.tags.name LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(:keyword)) AND (p.open IS TRUE)")
```

I have looked at the documentation but I don't see any option to manage this, what is the best way to go here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since multiple `tag`s can be associated with a `post` the relationship is a `@OneToMany` from `Post` to `Tag`. A `join` should work in this scenario.

Try this.

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Post p left join p.tags pTags WHERE (p.content LIKE CONCAT('%',LOWER(:keyword),'%' OR pTags.name LIKE CONCAT('%',LOWER(:keyword)) AND (p.open IS TRUE)")
```

**PS** : I have not tested this, but it should work.

Comment: Yes, finally I did it like this. I though that Spring Data has another way to do that but this is the only answer in this case. It is working perfectly, thanks!